# Windows 7 on Macbook Air 1,1 *without* Boot Camp

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, startup, windows, driver

I'm trying to install Windows 7 on an early 2008 (1,1) Apple Macbook air, on which OS X is *not* present. The machine is not able to boot directly the win 7 iso, supposedly because it lacks some support drivers (if you press `alt` at boot, it sees the external CD, but then the screen goes black)

Since Boot Camp Assistant "erases the external drive and copies the Windows ISO image and support software to it", I'd like to do this process on my own, either under Linux or in Windows

Can anyone instruct me how to do it, if it's doable?

Note: I'm note interested in partitioning instructions, just how to make it boot win 7 with working screen, keyboard and mouse